# monkeyrunner hangs when making a connection to the device

Tags: android, multithreading, adb, monkeyrunner

Here's what I need to do. I have 2 devices which I need to test using monkeyrunner. It is an automated test using python and monkeyrunner. I want to execute the test simultaneously for the 2 devices so I thought of using thread.

here's the code

> import threading
>
> import datetime import os, sys
>
> import ConfigParser from com.android.monkeyrunner
>
> import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice,MonkeyImage from datetime
>
> import datetime import hashlib from java.net
>
> import SocketException from com.ziclix.python.sql
>
> import zxJDBC
>
> def UseThread(data1, data2, data3, devID, Code, ScreenshotRef,
>   logFile):
>
> ```
>  device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10, devID)
>
> 'threaded code'
>
> 'initialization'
> ```
>
> file = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**)) +
>   '\Samples.txt','r') while 1:
>
> while 1:
>       line = file.readline()
>
> ```
> if not line:
>
>     print 'Done!'
>
>     break
>
> else:
>
>     line
>
>
> val=line.split('\t')
>
> data1 = val[0]
>
> data2 = val[1]
>
> data3 = val[2]
>
> threads = []
>
> for Code in cp.options('p'):
>
>     devID = cp.get('product',Code).strip()
>
>     ScreenshotRef = cp.get('source','ScreenshotRef') + '\\' + prodCode.upper()
>
>     logFile = outputFolder + '\\' + prodCode.upper() + '\\logs.txt' 
>
>     t=threading.Thread(target=UseThread,args=(data1, data2, data3, devID, prodCode, ScreenshotRef, logFile))
>     threads.append(t)
>     t.start()
>
> for i in range(0,len(threads)):
>     threads[i].join()
> ```

The problem is this. When the while loops finish one run and proceed to 2nd run, the code hangs in the part when monkeyrunner is waiting for connection. To be exact, this is the part where it stops

> device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10, devID)

the message says "Monkey command wake".

I assume that the problem has something to do with the connection, not with the thread because I tried to print something before that line which makes a connection and it works.

Is there an issue making a connection when you have already made one? do I need to close the previous connection first?

Comment: you cannot initiate connection for same device twice in an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonkeyRunner waitForConnection works only for one device. You cannot run this twice. You can run from another instance

Comment: Not accurately correct. MonkeyRunner waitForConnection works for multiple devices, though NOT simultaneously. I can run waitForConnection in a sequence (one after the other) for each device, pass that handle to the Thread and the threads can do the tests simultaneously on each of the devices.